# Why no indefinite article in "playing at basketball"?

Tags: indefinite-article

I'm a confused by the way Mick used the [indefinite](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/112772/is-playing-on-mini-basketball-hoop-alone-playing-basketball) article **"a"** in his comment:

> You could say that the child is playing at basketball, or playing with a basketball.

Why does the phrase *"at basketball"* not have an article, whereas the phrase *"with a basketball"* has the indefinite article **"a"**?

My guess would be that the key point here is the preposition (at) that in the first case prevents its use, whereas, in the second case the preposition (with) calls for its use, but I'm not sure either whether there's such a thing in English as the preposition to be decisive in the indefinite article use or what other rule may govern this situation.

Comment: It's the difference between the game called basketball, and the object called a basketball, which is used in the game of basketball

Comment: The prepositions have nothing to do with the matter. You can be sitting *at a table* or *playing with your brother*, for example. @Au101 has it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an idiomatic expression:

> *[**To play at**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+at): 1. To pretend to be or to do something for amusement or out of curiosity; 2. To do or take part in something halfheartedly:*

So in this case (as Au101 mentions in his comment) "to play at basketball" means  to play *the game* of basketball in a desultory manner, while to "play with a basketball" means to use the actual *ball*.

Other examples of "play at":

> She played at being a lawyer, but her heart was always set on politics.
>
> The soldiers played at dice while they were waiting for the enemy to attack.
>
> People say he just plays at being a developer, but still, he's made millions off of his app.

Comment: Also, the sport 'basketball' is an uncountable noun; the physical object 'basketball' is a countable noun.

Comment: @JohnFeltz  True, but you actually can't "play at" a countable noun.  You can only "play at" an activity.  "He played at a basketball" is not idiomatic.

Comment: Agreed.  But you can 'play at billiards', which a learner might think was plural...